# BorderLayout doesn't honor maximumsize

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, boxlayout

I have a problem using `BorderLayout`, but first of all, here is my GUI setup:

[image]

As you can see, I have 3 different components inside my `JFrame`. Adding the `JMenu` and `JList` works fine. But my `JPanel` should have a **fixed size** so I want to prevent my `BorderLayout` from stretching the panel. I tried everything, `setPreferredSize() setMinimumSize() setMaximumSize() setSize()` but again the layout stretches my panel to fit to the frame. (The panel is added to the frame using `BorderLayout.CENTER`).

Is there any way to prevent this or do you have other suggestions to manage the problem?

Comment: Add the blue panel to a panel that uses `GridBagLayout`. Add the GBL panel at `BoxLayout.CENTER`. The GBL panel will be stretched, but should honor the preferred size of the blue panel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you mean `BorderLayout`, not `BoxLayout`, because there is no `BoxLayout.CENTER` and it looks like you use a `BorderLayout` to place the components.

I think the problem here is that you only set the preferred size of the panel that you add to `BorderLayout.CENTER`. This doesn't have any effect. Instead you need nested layouts.

In this example I added the `JPanel` called `centerPanel`, which is using a standard `GridBagLayout` (to center the added component), to `BorderLayout.CENTER`. Then I added the additional `JPanel` called `panel`, which has a custom `preferrdSize`, to `centerPanel`. This way `panel` won't get stretched.

[image]

---

**Code:**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Example {

    public Example() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));

        DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
        JList<String> list = new JList<String>(listModel);
        list.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 0, 1, Color.BLACK));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(400, 400);
            }
            // Uncomment the following lines if you also want to prevent the
            // 'wrapping' of the panel.
            /*
             * @Override public Dimension getMinimumSize() { return new
             * Dimension(400, 400); }
             */
        };
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            menuBar.add(new JMenu("Menu " + i));
            listModel.addElement("Element " + i);
            panel.add(new JLabel("Label " + i));
        }

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        centerPanel.add(panel);

        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        contentPanel.add(list, BorderLayout.WEST);
        contentPanel.add(centerPanel);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(contentPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Example();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add your existing `JPanel` to a `JPanel` having `Flowlayout`, the default, or having `GridBagLayout` with default constraints. Add this panel to the frame's center, `BorderLayout.CENTER` by default.

```
Panel centerPane = new Panel(new GridBagLayout())`;
centerPane.add(yourJPanel);
frame.add(centerPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Also consider using `Box`, rather than a `JPanel` having `BoxLayout`.

Also consider using the frame's `setJMenuBar()`, rather than `add(BorderLayout.PAGE_START)`.